# Projector and OpenCV

Tags: opencv

Is there any difference between drawing picture on computer and projecting it on projector in OpenCV? 
One option is to project computer screen where everything is displayed. But maybe there is also such option as drawing and projecting images exactly on projector, using computer only as machine for calculations. If I could do that, I have to use some special functions and features of OpenCV or not?

Comment: I did not understand anything, what is a projector? Can you define your problem in different terms?

Comment: If you want to draw just to a projector, I'm guessing you'd have to use some OS specific commands for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Projectors use the same interfaces/cables as regular screens. An application rarely even knows (nor cares) what type of display it is connected to.
OpenCV (or actually HighGUI) displays images to the currently connected display, be that a CRT/LCD monitor or a projector.